# JPanel buttons and such

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So I'm doing this *http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futoshiki* and I have my JPanel with my buttons (5x5), now I need to insert a random number (3-7) of < or > operators in between some buttons as per the image.
How would I go about doing that? I'm not asking for the code, but rather for the logic one would use to complete such a task. These operators must of course be legal, as they'll be used later to solve the game.

```
public class Test implements ActionListener {
    JButton[][] gumbi = new JButton[5][5];

public Test() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5));

    Random op = new Random();
    int operatorji = op.nextInt(5) + 3;     //the random number of operators

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            gumbi[i][j] = new JButton("0");
            gumbi[i][j].addActionListener(this);
            panel.add(gumbi[i][j]);
        }
    }   

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Also, how would I also add ∨ and ∧ operators (vertically speaking)?

Comment: I think you should use a `JLabel` or something. Aside from that, I don't think inserting a random number of the operators would give a puzzle with exactly one solution.. unless I'm not understanding the game correctly.

Comment: Please explain your game and code's desired behavior. Also you'll want to improve your question title to one that gives us useful information about your problem, that summarizes your problem. Your current title is distinctly uninformative and gives little more than what the question tags already tell us.

Comment: My question: how do I insert operators in my Jpanel between my buttons in a legal way? (so that they can be used - like you see in the link's image)  As for the title, I don't know exactly what to call this, so... if anyone has a better title you can edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I would do based on your code:

- Make some horizontal and vertical gaps between buttons (to make space for operators)
- For displaying operators, I would just draw them on the panel
- I would write a method like `drawOperator(String operator, int h, int v, Graphics2D g)`, using h, v to locate the operator (imaging a X*X grid system to locate the operator), and somehow draw the operator into the correct gap between buttons.
- The locations of these operators can also be randomly generated (since the location is an imaginary X*X grid)

Might be a little too much for a small exercise though ^^

Comment: I know that this is one solution, but I've been told there is an easier way to do it.